# Android Google oAuth2 "/oauth2/v4/token" request show exception file not found

Tags: android, google-oauth

Application require google refresh token, I try to call service based on google OAuth2 doc.

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp

Step 5: Exchange authorization code for refresh and access tokens

**Service throw exception.**

> "java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"

**Use Service like :**

> POST /oauth2/v4/token HTTP/1.1  Host: www.googleapis.com Content-Type:
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> code=4/P7q7W91a-oMsCeLvIaQm6bTrgtp7& client_id=your_client_id&
>   client_secret=your_client_secret&
>   redirect_uri=https://oauth2.example.com/code&
>   grant_type=authorization_code

**Sample code :**

```
class getTokenAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String JsonResponse = "";
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            HttpURLConnection urlConn;

            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token");
                String client_id = "******9-tt3qav2d2rp45sgjqp5helrsbvc22kdq.apps.googleusercontent.com";
                String client_secret = ""; //This value is not needed for clients registered as Android, iOS, or Chrome applications.
                String redirect_uri = "http://localhost";
                String grant_type = "authorization_code";
                String code = params[0]; // serverAuthCode code
                HashMap<String, String> params1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params1.put("client_id", client_id);
                params1.put("client_secret", client_secret);
                params1.put("grant_type", grant_type);
                params1.put("redirect_uri", redirect_uri);
                params1.put("code", code);  // your code received

                Set set = params1.entrySet();
                Iterator i = set.iterator();
                StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> param : params1.entrySet()) {
                    if (postData.length() != 0) {
                        postData.append('&');
                    }
                    postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
                    postData.append('=');
                    postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
                }
                byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

                HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                for (String line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
                    builder.append(line).append("\n");
                }
                reader.close();
                conn.disconnect();
                System.out.println("token returned: " + builder.toString());

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Please suggest me, How to call service and received refresh token id in android app.

Comment: Unless I'm not mistaking, this logic should be even handled from the server side...

Answer (score 0):

```
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

should be

```
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

since you're sending a post request.